# How to find the function of a double integral from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the volume of the region bounded by $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=25$ in the first quadrant. I know that $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so from that, I can deduce that the region is bounded by two circles, one with a radius of 2 and another with a radius of 5. I also know that a full turn is equal to $2\pi$, so the first quadrant would be equal to a quarter of that, $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$. I suppose the radius integral would have limits of $2$ and $5$ and the angle integral would have limits of $0$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, I cannot figure out what function I have to integrate in order to find the volume.

Comment: The function is $1$ (in Cartesian coordinates). In general $\iint_R 1 \, dV$ is the volume of the region $R$. Converting to polar, $dV$ becomes $r \, drd\theta$, so the function you should integrate is just $r$.

Comment: So then would the function be rdrdθ or r^2drdθ?

Comment: Just $r$. It is $1$, before converting to polar, so it is $r$ after. You can see (without doing an integral) that the area should be $\frac{21 \pi}{4}$, since it is just the area between two circles. Do the integral both ways and see that only one gives the right answer.